# Question about Diophantine equations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

Solve the Diophantine equation.

> $6x+ 9y = 15$

We can see that $x = 1$ and $y=1$ solves the equation, so all solutions are given by $x = 1 + 3n$ and $y = 1 - 2n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. By using:

$$x=x_0 + n \times \frac{b}{gcd(a,b)}$$ and $$y=y_0 - n \times \frac{a}{gcd(a,b)}$$

However, solving it as my textbook says I get:

I get that $gcd(9,6)=3$

> $9 = 1 \times 6 + 3$
>
> $6 = 2 \times 3 + 0 $

Then,

> $3 = 9 - (1\times 6)$

So,

> $3=6(-1) + 9(1) \implies 15 = 6(-5) + 9(5)$

All solutions are given by (as it is stated in my textbook) $$x=x_0 - n \times \frac{b}{gcd(a,b)}$$ and $$y=y_0 + n \times \frac{a}{gcd(a,b)}$$

Thus,

> $x = - 5 - 3n$ and $y = 5 + 2n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

My textbook give the answer as $ x=1+3n, y= 1-2n$, how did they arrive at that by using $$x=x_0 - n \times \frac{b}{gcd(a,b)}$$ and $$y=y_0 + n \times \frac{a}{gcd(a,b)}$$

and $$3=6(-1) + 9(1)?$$

All I get is $x=-1 -3n, y= 1 + 2n,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ which gives $3$ and not $15$, or $x = - 5 - 3n, y = 5 + 2n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ which gives $15$ but looks ugly. What am I missing?

Comment: Your answer is the same as the textbook

Comment: Well, it's a matter of convention. $(1,1)$ for $(x,y)$ merely has the smallest solution in terms of absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x_0,y_0$ that are solutions, you can use the formula:
$$x=x_0+n\cdot\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\ ,\ y=y_0-n\cdot\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}$$
But you can also change the sign, and use the formula like this:
$$x=x_0-n\cdot\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\ ,\ y=y_0+n\cdot\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}$$
It doesn't matter.

Now, the textbook used $(1,1)=(x_0,y_0)$ and he used the first formula, so he got $x=1+3n\ ,\ y=1-2n$. You used $(-5,5)=(x_0,y_0)$, and the second formula, so you have got $x=-5-3n\ ,\ y=5+2n$, but it's all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Given $6x+9y=15\implies 2x+3y=5$

\begin{equation}
x = \frac{(5 - 3 y)}{2}\quad\land\quad y =\frac{(5 - 2 x)}{3}
\end{equation}
A pattern in a spreadsheet suggests $\quad x = (3 n + 1), n\in\mathbb{Z}\quad$
and, by substitution we get

\begin{equation}
y =\frac{(5 - 2 (3n-1)}{3}=\frac{(5 - 6n+1)}{3}=\frac{(6 - 6n)}{3}=(1-2n)
\end{equation}

$$\therefore\quad x = (3 n + 1),\quad y = (1 - 2 n), \quad n \in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$(x,y)\in\{\cdots, (-5,5), (-2,3),(1,1),(4,-1),(7,-3),\cdots\}$$